# How to write video then download using cv2 in Google colab?

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to do some image processing on a video, then save the resulting video using opencv on colab. However, I am not able to access the resulting video file that I am writing to.

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_file)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc,30.0,(1124,1080))
cnt = 0
ret = True
while(ret):

  ret,frame = cap.read()
  print(cnt,end=' ')

  # check if prey was tracked on this frame
  match = np.where(prey_frames==cnt)[0]
  if match:
    prey_frame = match[0]
    # print(prey_frame)
    image = cv2.circle(frame,(int(prey_px[prey_frame].x),95+int(prey_px[prey_frame].y)),
                       radius=5,color=(255,0,255),thickness=2)
  else:
    image = frame

  out.write(image)
  cnt += 1

out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

From what I understand, this should write to a file called 'output.mp4'. This code runs without error, but there is no file in the current directory, and no file of that name available to download (using `files.download('output.mp4')` returns 'cannot find file' error).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this problem a few times and I believe that it has to do with the fact that Colab's operating environment only supports a few video encodings.
I was able to get the video writer working with the following:

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F','M','P','4')`